# pass GET parameter to href link

Tags: python, django

I have question and don't know how to express it to find the answer

when I go to : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/test/?title="test"`
and then want to go to another page,it will go to : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/test/?page=2"`
I kow it should go to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/test/?title="test&page=2"`
But don't know how to do it
How can I edit the url to pass the parameter(title="test) to go to the correct url ?

And I have a second question about urls too

if I'm now on path

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/test/?title="test`

How can I write the absolute href to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/test/` ?

Please help me Thanks

test.html :

```
<form action="" method="get"  class="searchtitle">
      search title:<input type="text" name="title">
        <button type="submit" value="submit" >search</button>
</form>
...
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if contacts.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    <span class="current">
        Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>
    {% if contacts.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="" method="get">
         <td>GO to</td>
         <td><input name="page" type="text" ></td>
         td> page </td>
         <td><input type="submit" value=" go to page "></td>
         </form>
</span>
```

views.py:

```
def object_list_1(request, model):
    if request.GET.get("title", None):
        search_term = request.GET['title']
        cls = get_model('mongo', model)
        obj_list = cls.objects.filter(title__contains=search_term)   
        results = get_paginator(request, obj_list, 10)
        template_name = 'filterimgs/%s_list.html' % model.lower()
        return render_to_response(template_name, {'object_list': obj_list,'contacts': results},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this `<a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">`; here you are ignoring any query string (the `?title="test"` part).

To fix this problem, you need to first [enable the request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request), and then update your template so that it includes the full URL, like this:

```
<a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ contact.previous_page_number }}">
```

Comment: I found this will have a problem.if I click next page continuously.the url will become  ````http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/test/?title="test&page=2&page=3&page=4```` Because it is base on ````request.get_full_path ````